# How to control media service from activity?

Tags: java, android, service, media-player

I have the next situation - I develop the music app,  it contains media service.
Also the app contains MainActivity with 4 Fragments in it. In the bottom of each Fragment there is a bar with play, skip next, skip previouse, shuffle and repeat, it looks like that:[image: the bar in the bottom refers to MainActivity]

The bar in the bottom refers to MainActivity.
Also in Albums tab and Playlist tab  there are lists of albums and playlists which you can tap and it will take you to another activity with songs from taped album/playlist. I have only one service, so I bind it to all of it(one Fragment, two activities, actually I have leak but it is another problem)

The question is how can I control media playback(skipnext/previouse, play/pause, shuffle, repeat) from that bar in the bottom.

I already set `OnClickListener` on buttons and tried to call service method, but in that case I have an error like: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying()' on a null object reference`

I tried both: 
`private MediaPlayerService mediaPlayerService = MediaPlayerService.getInstance()`
and just in case 
`private MediaPlayerService mediaPlayerService = new MediaPlayerService()`(of course last one doesn't work)

I tried to make `mediaPlayer` singleton and yes it works, but there is another problem with skipNext/Previouse - int songPosition and (ArrayList) of ids should be singleton as well (or static in the class), good, I made it, but then another problem `prepareAsync` called in state 1 error... W@T@F@... sorry, that is my first project and maybe I made simple things very complicated developing bycicle. Any help will be great. 
Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I just thought to use messanger class, didn't try it yet..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I found an answer and be honest it wasn't very hard. Actually what I forgot to do is to bind service to MainActivity, after I did it, everything goes well.